# Use different Windows account in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, windows, plsql

Is it possible to use/log in to a different account in pl/sql. For example, I would like to write to a file in a folder only a specific account has access to. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
Other code...
LOG_IN_OTHER_USER('SPECIALUSER', 'SECRETPASSWORD');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(OutputFile,the_outfile);
UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(OutputFile);
LOG_OFF_OTHER_USER('SPECIALUSER');
Other code...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming 11g.
There are a few ways to do this. Easiest is to use the Oracle Job Scheduler with the Remote Job Agent. That agent can run using credentials for a qualified OS account. You could run a job that selects data from the database and spools it in the required output directory.

You could also copy a file to the Remote Job agent. This is closest to the code flow you described. For docu and examples see [the book I wrote](https://www.packtpub.com/mastering-oracle-scheduler-in-oracle-11g-databases/book) about the Oracle Scheduler.

There are no ways to switch OS accounts directly in pl/sql because whatever you do in the database, you are using the credentials of the Oracle Database Instance. The Oracle Remote Job Agent can use own credentials and is accessible from within pl/sql by using the dbms_scheduler package.

Answer (score 3):

No, but there are ways to do what you are trying to do.

PL/SQL runs with the same OS context and permissions as the Oracle service, so even if you run a procedure as the other windows user, the OS permissions in the PL/SQL will still match the Oracle services.  In order to get around this you will have to in some way get the data to where the other user can pick it up or have the other user get the data directly from the database.  Here are two ideas, but there are probably many more.

You could create the file in a location that can be reached and then have a job running in the context of the other user that moves it to the protected folder.

Another way would be to have a client application build the file itself logged in as the other user.  ik_zelf's answer has an excellent way to do this.